# Unexpected end of input in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to load a JSON file through javaScript. I have place button in the HTML that executes the function `loadAJAX`. But I keep getting an error on line 11 `var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);` that says `unexpected end of input`. I have checked several times and cant find a solution to this. [Test SITE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/ajax_json/)

**script.js**

```
function loadAJAX() {
    var request;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    request.open("GET", "data.json");
    request.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if((request.status === 200) && (request.readyState === 4)){
                var items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                var output = "<ul>";
                for (var key in items){
                    output += "<li>" + items[key].colorName + "</li>";
                }
                output += "</ul>";
                document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = output;


            }
    };
    request.send();
}
```

data.json

```
  {
    "colorsArray":[{
            "colorName":"red",
            "hexValue":"#f00",
            "info" : "My favorite color."
        },
        {
            "colorName":"green",
            "hexValue":"#0f0",
            "info" : "Old color for old things, like food ew."

        },
        {
            "colorName":"blue",
            "hexValue":"#00f",
            "info" : "Reminds me of bruised arm."
        },
        {
            "colorName":"cyan",
            "hexValue":"#0ff",
            "info" : "Not an idea what color this is."
        },
        {
            "colorName":"magenta",
            "hexValue":"#f0f",
            "info" : "Every girl talks about her color being this."
        },
        {
            "colorName":"yellow",
            "hexValue":"#ff0",
            ""info" : "My mom likes yellow."
        },
        {
            "colorName":"black",
            "hexValue":"#000",
            "info" : "Well now look at this color the new white lol."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `data.json` is empty.

Comment: Paste the json.  Or verify it yourself at http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Blender Sorry fixed that issue.

Comment: @PaulTomblin I now included the json to my question.

Comment: `""info" : "My mom likes yellow."` Too many quotes.

Comment: The highlighted code show that your JSON is invalid `""info" : "My mom likes yellow."`

Comment: Like I said, check it with jsonlint.com

Comment: Or just look at the syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ya, like everyone suggested, you should really think about using a plugin or linter to debug your json response.  Something like JSONView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"info: Old color for old things, like food ew."`

You've accidentally quoted the whole line here. The name and value of an object property need to be quoted separately. Rewrite as

`"info": "Old color for old things, like food ew."`

This also masks a duplicated quote character further down:

`""info" : "My mom likes yellow."`

There should be only one in front of the key name `info`.

Comment: Oh yea I fixed that issue but still not getting a response back